# show AdMob interstitial ads without button click ios

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase, admob

i made a app with Xcode (swift) and i have implemented AdMob interstitial ads in the app but the only way i know to show the ad is click the button and ad will show, i want to show ads in webView without any button click , like when someone is scrolling down after some seconds ad will pop up. is thats possible ?

this is whats i am currently using

```
 var interstital: GADInterstitial!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


    interstital = GADInterstitial(adUnitID: "")

    let request = GADRequest()
    interstital.load(request)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func Ad(_ sender: Any) {

    if (interstital.isReady) {

        interstital.present(fromRootViewController: self)
        interstital = CreateAd()
    }

}



func CreateAd() -> GADInterstitial {

    let interstital = GADInterstitial (adUnitID: "")
    interstital.load(GADRequest())
    return interstital
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this you can use Timers, which allow you to execute a function,`CreateAd()` in your case, after an amount of time. In the example below I make it display an interstitial ad after 20-200 seconds. To change the minimum and maximum interval just change those numbers. I also removed the part which redeclares interstitial each time as setting it once in `viewDidLoad` is enough.

```
class YourViewController: UIViewController {
    var interstital: GADInterstitial!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
       interstital = GADInterstitial(adUnitID: "")

       let request = GADRequest()
       interstital.load(request)

       let randomTime = Double(arc4random() + 20).truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 200.0) 
       Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: randomTime, target: self, selector: #selector(YourViewController.CreateAd), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)


    }
    func CreateAd() -> GADInterstitial {

        if (interstital.isReady) {

            interstital.present(fromRootViewController: self)
            let randomTime = Double(arc4random() + 20).truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 200.0)
            Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: randomTime, target: self, selector: #selector(YourViewController.CreateAd), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
        }
    }
}
```

*I had to nest the timers instead of setting `repeats` to true to make the interval random each time.*

Comment: hello sir, but i am seeing error , cannot convert value of type 'Timeinterval.Type' (aka 'Double.Type) to expected argument type ''Timeinterval' (aka 'Double')

Comment: First of all sorry for my late respons. I see I forgot to update the last line, the answer should now work.

Answer (score 0):

Using the timer, here is the implementation for the objective c. Here new random timer will fire within 20sec to 200sec once the add is closed.

```m
self.interstitial = [self createAndLoadInterstitial];

double time = (arc4random() % 200) + 20;
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:time target:self selector:@selector(showAdIfReady) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
```

```m
- (void)showAdIfReady {
    if (self.interstitial.isReady) {
        [self.interstitial presentFromRootViewController:self];

    } else {
        NSLog(@"Ad wasn't ready");
    }

}
```

```m
- (void)interstitialDidDismissScreen:(GADInterstitial *)interstitial {
    self.interstitial = [self createAndLoadInterstitial];
    double time = (arc4random() % 200) + 20;
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:time target:self selector:@selector(showAdIfReady) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
}
```